# What is this descriptor of a bag?

Tags: translation

**What is this descriptor of a bag?**

I know the first line is "Bag.", but what's the second?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It says:

> ケロヨンストラップ[付]{つき}。 Comes with Keroyon (cell phone?) charm/strap.

ケロヨン↓

[image]
<sub>(source: [naganoblog.jp](http://img01.naganoblog.jp/usr/n/a/w/nawateribbit/IMG_0912.JPG))</sub>

Comment: (多くの人が「ケロヨン」だと思っているのは、[実は「ケロヨン」ではなくて「ケロちゃん」](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B1%E3%83%AD%E3%83%A8%E3%83%B3#.E3.81.9D.E3.81.AE.E4.BB.96)なのだそうです・・・)